# Вывод даты JS в VSCode отстает на пару часов

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Я написал код, который должен выводить дату

```
let date = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 18, 0, 0);
console.log(date);
```

Если я правильно понял, то в консоль должно вывести 2018 год, 1 января 18 часов

Вот что выводится в консоль:
`2018-01-01T13:00:00.000Z`

Та же дата, только отстает на пять часов. Подскажите пожалуйста, так и должно быть? Или что-то не так? Писал в редакторе VSCode

Comment: Где вы это запускаете? Вообще-то обычно дата выводится в текущем часовом поясе. Попробуйте принудительно сделать из неё строку

Answer (score 0):

Всё потому что дата в JS хранится по гринвичу (UTC), но создаёте Вы её от своего локального времени.

Приводите к её к нужному часовому поясу или к строке (автоматическое преобразование к локальному часовому поясу), тогда отобразится верное время:

```js
let date = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 18, 0, 0);
console.log(date);

console.log(date.toLocaleString("ru-RU", {
  timeZone: "Europe/Moscow"
}))
console.log(date.toString())
```

Для более удобной работы с датами лучше использовать [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

Comment: Date в JS хранится как число миллисекунд с «начала времён».